# How to get an image above background while shadowing background in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have an image and I want it to appear on my screen, above my background, with keeping background a bit dark type like in the image. I am thinking on using `AlertDialog` to display the image, but if you think there is a better way of doing it or a specific widget for this, please do tell me. Also please tell me what do we name this kind of image which hovers over background and focusing itself in UI.

```
enter code here
```

[image]

Just for trying out, I used this in my screen's initstate, as I want it to appear as soon as my screen appears -

```
super.initState();
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext buildContext) {
        return AlertDialog(
          content: Center(
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.red,
              width: 200,
              height: 200,
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    );
```

Comment: what is missing on `AlertDialog` can you include your test code?

Comment: I am trying to display it using initState, as I have to make it appear on starting of screen, this error is coming -  

When an inherited widget changes, for example if the value of Theme.of() changes, its dependent widgets are rebuilt. If the dependent widget's reference to the inherited widget is in a constructor or an initState() method, then the rebuilt dependent widget will not reflect the changes in the inherited widget.

Comment: Can you attach sample code to test it out?

Answer (score 1):

`initState` doesn't contain `context` you can get context after first frame.

You can use  `addPostFrameCallback`

```dart
 WidgetsBinding.instance?.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) {
      showDialog(..);}
```

Or `Future.delayed`

```dart
 Future.delayed(Duration.zero).then((value) {
      showDialog(..); }
```

The dialog construction is :

```dart
  showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext buildContext) {
          const double iconSize = 48;
          return LayoutBuilder(
            builder: (context, constraints) => AlertDialog(
              backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
              elevation: 0,
              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
              content: SizedBox(
                width: constraints.maxWidth * .75,
                height: constraints.maxHeight * .75,
                child: Stack(
                  children: [
                    ///background image with fit Cover
                    Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      child: Container(
                        width: constraints.maxWidth * .75 - iconSize,
                        height: constraints.maxHeight * .75 - iconSize,
                        color: Colors.cyanAccent,
                      ),
                    ),

                    Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.topRight,
                      child: GestureDetector(
                        onTap: () {
                          Navigator.of(context).pop();
                        },
                        child: Container(
                          decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                              color: Colors.white, shape: BoxShape.circle),
                          child: const Icon(
                            Icons.close,
                            size: iconSize,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
      );
```

[image]

Comment: I have a global variable url. Initially, it is null, but in some other files, I am calling a function to fetch it's value using an API. Now, I want that as soon as url's value becomes not null, display this on the screen. Can you help me with this?

Comment: Feel free to raise a separate question showing your effort.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Stack` widget withe ***three*** widget as children.

first children widget is your background screen.

second children widget is a `Container` widget with color `.withOpacity()`.

third children widget is the image you are trying to show on top.

Like this:

```
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          Container(
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
          Container(
            color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.5),
          ),
          Center(
            child: Container(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 70 / 100,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 80 / 100,
              color: Colors.purple,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
```

for `Visibility` issue you can use this.

```
bool isVisible = false;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          Container(
            color: Colors.red,
            child: Center(
              child: Container(
                child: TextButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    setState(() {
                      isVisible = true;
                    });
                  },
                  child: Text('Show Widget'),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Visibility(
            visible: isVisible,
            child: GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                setState(() {
                  isVisible = false;
                });
              },
              child: Container(
                color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.5),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Visibility(
            visible: isVisible,
            child: Center(
              child: Container(
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 70 / 100,
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 80 / 100,
                color: Colors.purple,
                child: Stack(
                  children: [
                    Positioned(
                      top: 0.0,
                      right: 0.0,
                      child: IconButton(
                        icon: const Icon(
                          Icons.close,
                          color: Colors.white,
                        ),
                        onPressed: () {
                          setState(() {
                            isVisible = false;
                          });
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: But how would I close it when user taps outside of the window or taps on cross button? By using visibility?

Comment: @ShreyanshSharma , I added code to answer.